# Invalid left-hand side in assignment | Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Im just trying to test if my bot works, I am pretty sure I have done everything correctly but there seems to be a problem. Every time I run my ping command it throws an error at me.

Error:

```
(node:9304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\blade\commands\ping.js:10:38)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\blade\bot.js:55:42)
```

My Ping.js code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "test command",

    async run (client, message, args) {


        const ping = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`\`${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}\`ms`);


        message.channel.send(ping);
    }
}
```

And this is the reference of bot.js:55:42 :

```
client.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;

        try {
            client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args); // This line
        } catch (error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
})
```

I am sorry if this seems to be a stupid question, I'm sorry in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following code:

```
client.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
}
```

And for some reason it worked.